# Event hub to databricks error as stream is terminated?

Tags: pyspark, azure-eventhub, azure-databricks

I've been trying to set up a proof of concept were Azure Databricks reads data from my Event Hub using the following code:

```
connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://mystream.servicebus.windows.net/;EntityPath=theeventhub;SharedAccessKeyName=event_test;SharedAccessKey=mykeygoeshere12345"

ehConf = {
  'eventhubs.connectionString' : connectionString
}

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()

readEventStream = df.withColumn("body", df["body"].cast("string"))
display(readEventStream)
```

I'm using the azure_eventhubs_spark_2_11_2_3_6.jar package as recommeneded [here](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/18337/error-some-streams-terminated-before-this-command.html) but i've tried the latest version and keep getting the message

```
ERROR : Some streams terminated before this command could finish!
```

I've used the databricks runtime version 6.1, and rolled it back to 5.3 but can't seem to get it up and running. I have a Python script that sends data to the event hub, I just can't see anything coming out of it?
Is it the package? or something else I'm doing wrong?

Update: I was loading the library from a JAR file that I downloaded. I deleted that and then got it from the Maven repo. After testing it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works perfectly with the below configuration:

**Databrick Runtime:** 5.5 LTS (includes Apache Spark 2.4.3, Scala 2.11)

**Azure EventHub library:** com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.13

Use above configuration, able to get stream the data from Azure Eventhubs.

[image]

**Reference:** [Integrating Apache Spark with Azure Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-spark-connector)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had loaded the library via a JAR file, I changed it to load from Maven, and it worked. Thanks